# SQL Server Select all except data where next row has datediff of less than 10 milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and i'm facing an issue.
I have the following data (sample seen below).

[image]

What i want is to select all the cardnumbers, except these that are followed by an event that contains the same `cardnumber` while the `result` value is `not ok`.

Their time difference between these two events is at most 200 milliseconds (so i believe in the where clause it must be `datediff(ms, cardnumberofpreviousevent, cardnumberofnextevent) > 200.`

So in this case, the desirable outcome should be all the lines displayed above (line 426 to 433), except the checked line 432.

Can anyone give me some help? It will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at LAG and LEAD, they should be ideal for this situation. Link for LAG - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Dave Brown Yes this is indeed ideal for this situation, thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your question.

Did you try :

```
where datediff(ms, cardnumberofpreviousevent, cardnumberofnextevent) > 200
```

If it does not work, please include your whole query, then I will advise how to alter it...

Comment: No, i have tried this, it's not that simple.
Thank you for your reply though, at this time i have figured out what to do. 
I used the LEAD function and i've generated the desirable outcome.